# Jetpack Compose infinite loop after first render on button press

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I was trying some unusual things with compose while trying to read and understand the documentation with my friend. We have written a code in compose such as:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
     var count by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) } 
     var count2 by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) } 
    Column {         
          ChildComponent(count) 
          count++        
          ChildComponent(count) 
          ChildComponent2(count2) { 
                count2++        
          }     
    } 
}
 
@Composable
fun ChildComponent(value: Int) {
     Text(text = value.toString()) 
}
 
@Composable
fun ChildComponent2(value: Int, onClicked: () -> Unit) { 
    Button(onClick = onClicked) { 
        Text(text = value.toString()) 
    }
 }
```

The thing is, when we start the app with the above composables, the first render is successful. However, when we press the button, the app goes into an infinite loop. I am totally aware of all the side effects and mistakes in the code, but after hours of thinking, we could not find any logical reason for compose to do **a successful render in the beginning and starting to infinite loop after button press** even with that mistakes. What we were expecting was an infinite loop in the beginning. Any explanations?

All explanations are appreciated.

Comment: It requires a successful recomposition to schedule next one, you can observe this with SideEffect { count++ } too. It will trigger recomposition infinitely even if button is not pressed. The question here is how Composition assigns different values to 2 Text composables when your Composable first entered composition as you can see in official docs that snippet does not trigger recomposition until you increase count via Button either. It also make me question either why it doesn't trigger recomposition only the time a Composable enters composition. Very good question by the way

Comment: The only reason I can think of is this triggers infinite recomposition that why it's an infinite loop, why it doesn't trigger it in the first composition? The best think i can think of is that the first recomposition takes the initial value of mutableState(0) and it does not consider the count++ in it's composition because it's not UI related. But hey I'm just saying and as @Thracian mentioned this is a very good question

Comment: I also think it's not considered recomposition even if triggering recomposition inside SideEffect results infinite loop. But i'm really curious what causes the difference. I think it might be related to `$composer.end()?.updateScope` on first run but it's just a guess. You can check out this article for more details. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reason that first composition doesn't cause an infinite loop. The first is because a mutable state object is never considered changed in the snapshot it was created in. Since the first composition creates,

```
var count by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) } 
var count2 by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
```

in the first composition, any changes made to mutable state in that composition will not be considered a change. This is to allow complicated state to be created that cannot be easily reflected in a single constructor (e.g. a circular linked list cannot be constructed with a single constructor call for the elements of the list, at least one item needs to be modified after it was created to complete the cycle).

The second is because composition doesn't track changes to content that has not yet been added to the composition. Content created in a composition is not added until the apply changes phase which is after all composition functions have completed. For the above it is after the changes to the mutable state have been made so the changes are not considered "changed" as they didn't change after the content was added.

For these reason you should not change mutable state that has already been read in composition which seems you are aware of already. In general, a composable function should not change state, it should only read state. There are exceptions for derived state for which the results are stored in a mutable state object (such as a dynamic composition local) but the state read by the parent should never be modified by a child composable or, as in this example, you will infinitely recompose.

Any write to a state that has already been read is considered undefined behavior for Compose; it can literally do anything. The reason is that composable functions are supposed to be transforming state into a tree (in Compose UI, the LayoutNode tree to visualize a UI). For any state there should be one and only one valid transform of the data into a tree. If the state changes while the transform is running then there is no one valid result of the transform. If the data is changed before the transform reads it, there is still just one valid transform of the data as the data being transformed includes the modified data.

As the mutable state can be changed in any thread so Compose takes a snapshot of the data and will not see any changes made by any other thread while the transform is being run. Therefore, any violations of the single result must come from the transform itself.

Comment: Very good answer. Is there any official or semi-official, blog post or medium article, resource about how these transform works and this behavior we can read about? When it comes to Nodes and inner works there doesn't seem to be many especially up to date resources. Can you suggest any?

Comment: The Compose Internals book by https://jorgecastillo.dev/book/ covers some of this ground. Generally we don't document specifics about the internals of Compose as it is likely to change.