# How is compose able to do the recomposition when provided with non-state object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

See this below code first

```
class WellnessViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _tasks = getWellnessTasks().toMutableStateList()
    val tasks: List<WellnessTask>
        get() = _tasks
```

Now im passing tasks to composeFunction and any changes in the _tasks (adding or removing item) cause the composeFunction to recompose. But how exactly is this thing working since I'm providing the non state object to that function this the code below.

```
@Composable
fun WellnessScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    wellnessViewModel: WellnessViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        StatefulCounter()
        WellnessTasksList(
            list = wellnessViewModel.tasks,
            onCloseTask = {
                wellnessViewModel.remove(it)
            },
            onCheckedTask = { task, checked ->
                wellnessViewModel.changeTaskChecked(task, checked)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Why is this working and how, a simple explanation is needed for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But how exactly is this thing working since I'm providing the non
> state object to that function this the code below

Because SnapshotStateList is exactly a `StateObject`, and addition, deletion or updating an item with new instance triggers recomposition.

```
@Stable
class SnapshotStateList<T> : MutableList<T>, StateObject
```

`_tasks = getWellnessTasks().toMutableStateList()` is a `SnapshotStateList`. Any modification on that list, update requires new item to be set with if you wish to change properties, triggers recomposition since it's a StateObject. T
hat's the thing with SnapshotStateList it triggers recomposition for the items that changed. You can consider it like a mutableStateOf(list) but with selective recomposition instead passing a new list that recomposes every item.

Also when a lambda is not stable invoking it causes recomposition.

[Why does a composable recompose while seemingly being stateless (the only passed parameter is a function, not a state)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963088/why-does-a-composable-recompose-while-seemingly-being-stateless-the-only-passed?noredirect=1#comment135690235_76963088)

Also you can check this answer out how to optimize recomposition using SnapshotStateList, unstable lambdas and passing stable inputs instead of List which is unstable.

[Jetpack Compose lazy column all items recomposes when a single item update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699081/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-all-items-recomposes-when-a-single-item-update?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, "How does it work"

Comment: what does this "val tasks: List<WellnessTask>" have todo with SnapShot thing

Comment: It answers how it works, `_tasks = getWellnessTasks().toMutableStateList()` is a SnapshotStateList. Any modification on that list triggers recomposition since it's a StateObject. You can check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853) I pass a SnapshotStaetList to `fun ListScreen(people: List<Person>, onItemClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
` which triggers recomposition only for the items that changed. That's the thing with SnapshotStateList it triggers recomposition for the items that changed. You can consider it like a mutableStateOf(list) but with selective recomposition

Comment: SnapshotStateMap, SnapshotStateList and State/MutableState are state objects that trigger recomposition. Another factor that causes recomposition is stability of lambdas even when your inputs don't change. And for that i posted the link below or you can see in other answer to explain further why recomposition happens.

Comment: i will upvote and accept it as the answer, just clear me this one thing, ok i got it _tasks will get called every time when we change but but but -> (the main question) I'm not passing _tasks to the compose function, I'm passing task (whos data type is List<WellnessTask> <<<<------ how is this thing able to recompose compose function since its not the state data type, _tasks is i get but tasks is not

Comment: It's SnapshotStateList under the hood because of polymorphism. This is something about how compose works under the hood and schedules recomposition. When compose sees state objects change it schedules recomposition where, closes scopes, that States or when SnapshotStateList/Map used values inside list or map are read. You can check out source code if you wish. But even when i asked about this internals google dev didn't give much since internals are always subject to change. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956202/5457853

Comment: There was also a question where how Compose understands State reads also another one with SnapshotStateList, you can refer them about details how it works under the hood but generally these subjects are not explicitly explained by google.

Comment: List is an unstable class, at least as of now, even if you change in the second like i posted you don't have recomposition when other input, counter, change because of stability but again in whether you pass List or SnapshotStateList as input of a Composable function  it's a SnapshotStateList where Compose checks any of it's items are updated to schedule a recomposition

Comment: "because of polymorphism" in nutshell this answered the question